# Sonar - Exclude Cyclomatic Complexity Check on a Class

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am using Sonar for my Java project and there is a need to Exclude the Cyclomatic complexity check on one class only

I tried adding it as an exclusion under
**Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria**

With the Rule Key Pattern Of **squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity** 
and the File Path Pattern of 
**com/services/images/submission/impl/SubmissionScreenImageServiceImpl.java** but the file still gets included on Cyclomatic Checks

I am using Sonar 5.0.1

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `com` directory at the root of your project? If not, I would recommend to add:

- either a `*/` at the start of the File Path Pattern, giving `*/com/services/images/submission/impl/SubmissionScreenImageServiceImpl.java`
- or use the correct directory prefix; e.g this would be `src/main/java/` in a standard Maven project, giving `src/main/java/com/services/images/submission/impl/SubmissionScreenImageServiceImpl.java`

Comment: do you know if you can set these exclusions in a pom file if your using the sonar maven plugin as opposed to setting them on the sonar dashboard?

Comment: This is not recommended, the properties format to support this is not documented and subject to changes. What is your use case?

Comment: Ok fair enough. My reason for asking is I would just like to keep all settings in the 1 place if possible but if its not recommended I understand